# Unable to get test coverage for react using JEST

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, istanbul

I am trying to run JEST for the react code,it always shows PASS and not running any script written inside test folder.Inside coverage folder also i am not getting any components folder being created.kindly let me know how to fix it

following are my configurations

**package.json**

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.11.1",
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.7.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^4.1.6",
    "babel-jest": "^9.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "bower-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.9",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "es6-promise": "^3.2.1",
    "es6bindall": "0.0.5",
    "eslint": "^1.10.3",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.0.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-jest": "^0.2.0",
    "grunt-webpack": "^1.0.11",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "jasmine-ajax": "^3.2.0",
    "jest-cli": "^0.9.2",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
     "react": "^15.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.0",
    "react-fileupload": "^2.2.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.2.9",
    "react-router": "^2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "sinon": "^1.17.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "webpack",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "node_modules/.bin/eslint -f html app-client.js components > report.html || exit 0",
    "start": "node app-server.js"
  },
   "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/jest-script-preprocessor",
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "preprocessorIgnorePatterns": [
      "../frontend/node_modules/"
    ],
    "testFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "es6"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "es6"
    ],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [ 
      "react",
      "fbjs",
      "react-dom",
      "react-addons-test-utils",
      "es6bindall",
      "axios",
      "promise",
      "react-router",
      "sinon"
    ],
    "verbose": true 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The folder for your tests should be `__tests__` not `tests`. If you want to change that you need to use [testRegex](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#testregex-string) option.

If you want run it with coverage you can do:

`jest --coverage`

or in your script case:

`npm test -- --coverage`

Be aware that I am talking about latest version of Jest (14.x). You can find an [example](https://github.com/ferrannp/enzyme-example-jest) I wrote about setting up Jest and running tests with or without coverage.